# how to access attributes of list members AKA AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python and I get the this error when I try to access the name attribute of an object in a list.

In this first block of code I am able to print the name attribute of my Card class:

```
    while nextcard<=53:
        thisCard=Card()
        thisCard=thisCard.init_card(nextcard)
        base_deck.append(thisCard)
        print(base_deck[nextcard].name)
        nextcard+=1
```

I also have a class called Deck which has an list attribute called cards. I get the error when I try to print the name of a specific card in the list with the below code

```
    testDeck=Deck()
    if testDeck.d_count==42:
        testDeck.name="four player 500"
        testDeck.cards=[]
        testDeck.cards.append(base_deck[4:14])
        testDeck.cards.append(base_deck[17:27])
        testDeck.cards.append(base_deck[29:40])
        testDeck.cards.append(base_deck[42:53])
        print(testDeck.cards[2].name)
        nextcard=0
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your main problem is that you are appending lists to testDeck.cards, as opposed to appending individual cards. Lists don't have a .name() method, so you get the error.

Let's take a look with a simplified example. We create a simplified basedeck with four items.

```
>>> bd = []
>>> bd.append(1)
>>> bd.append(2)
>>> bd.append(3)
>>> bd.append(4)
>>> print(bd)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then we create a simplified list of cards. As we try to append slices from the basedeck, the append functions appends each slice as an **atomic** unit: basically creating a list with **sublists**, NOT as I presume you want, a list with **individual elements**.

```
>>> cards = []
>>> cards.append(bd[0:2])
>>> cards.append(bd[2:4])
>>> print(cards)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

To have slices added to a list as **individual elements**, you can use the **.extend()** method.

```
In [14]: cards2 = []
    ...: cards2.extend(bd[0:2])
    ...: cards2.extend(bd[2:4])
    ...: print(cards2)
    ...:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hope this helps.